# Restructuring the folders on a company drive

Tags: file-management, server

Recently I have been assigned the task of restructuring the current structure within a company drive - which is specific for the Reporting department.

Since this request I've requested a new drive on the server for migration purposes, using this blank slate what is the best approach to implement this task?

My thoughts currently are applying folder structure in line within the [Dewey Decimal System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification).

Side note: I am currently in talks with IT regarding limiting user editing within this drive. Preventing them from creating new folders etc.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [multi-media content](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/935/185), [code fragments](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. If you're looking for software, please [edit] your post accordingly to reflect that.